# Как получить результат обработки формы на той же странице, что и форма?

Tags: php

Когда нажимаю submit на index.php, исполняется select_res.php скрипт, но результат запроса вижу на новой, пустой странице.

Как можно ответ select запроса получать не на новой странице, а на главной, где кликнул на submit?

в index.php пишу:

```
<form action="select_res.php?type=<?php echo $_GET[type]?>" method="post">
<h3 align="left">FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value=""></h3>
<h3 align="left">LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="">    </h3><br>
<h3 align="left> <input type="submit" value="Verify">
</form>
```

а в select_res.php пишу:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("lottery", $db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT persons_id FROM persons WHERE 'FirstName'='".$_POST['FirstName']."'");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $myrow['persons_id'];
echo "Your ID:", $myrow['Persons_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Вариантов много, но вам скорее подойдет не сабмитить форму, а отправлять данные ajaxом (т.е. через js)

Comment: пока изучаю php и хочу решить задачу без ajax(пока). Вы говорите вариантов много, а какие?  Как можно без ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удивительно, но за два дня никто так и не смог дать правильный ответ.
Впрочем, этому есть объяснение - поскольку вопрос изначально содержит в себе противоречие, то чтобы на него ответить, его надо сначала внимательно разобрать и исправить неувязки.

Для начала -

### Три базовых правила при работе с протоколом НТТР

1. Запрос информации для показа **всегда** делается методом GET.
2. Запрос, который отправляет информацию на сервер, меняя его состояние, **всегда** делается методом POST.
3. После запроса, отправленного методом POST, сервер **всегда** перенаправляет клиента на какую-либо страницу методом GET.

Как можно увидеть, исходный вопрос противоречит вышеприведенным правилам, и не должен быть задан в такой форме. Попробуем его исправить.

Поскольку в текущем своем виде код не выглядит делающим что-либо осмысленное, мы не можем однозначно судить о его предназначении. Поэтому попробуем разобрать все варианты его осмысленного применения.

### Вариант 1. Лотерея.

Судя по названию БД, мы можем предположить, что этот код представляет собой показ результатов в некоей лотерее. Пользователь вводит имя и фамилию, а ему выводятся результаты.
Сверившись с вышеприведенными правилами мы можем определить, что у нас вариант №1 - запрос данных с сервера без изменения его состояния. То есть, **форма должна отправляться методом GET, причем сразу на главную.** (Как следствие вы можем отметить, что ответ, предлагающий редирект, является абсолютно бессмысленным в контексте данной задачи.)

Но теперь возникает другой вопрос - как нам поженить главную страницу, на которую приходит запрос, и обработчик запроса, который лежит в отдельном файле. 
Вариант тупо переписать код обработчика годится в качестве костыля, но в реальной жизни так никто не делает - главная очень быстро превратится в помойку, в которой сам черт ногу сломит. А вот разносить разный функционал по разным файлам - идея очень здравая! Так что нам бы надо и код в отдельном файле сохранить, и результат на главной отобразить. И тут нам на помощь приходит оператор `include`! Делаем так:

```
if(isset($_POST['FirstName']))
{
    include 'select_res.php';
}
```

и дальше уже пусть отдельный скрипт делает то что ему надо.

### Вариант 2. Авторизация.

Но с другой стороны, этот код не запрашивает из БД результат лотереи, а запрашивает айди пользователя. Такое обычно требуется при авторизации. Сверившись с Правилами мы видим, что это запрос, меняющий состояние сервера (на нем заводится сессия). То есть, в этом случае мы можем посылать запрос куда угодно, но только методом POST, и после его обработки необходимо сделать редирект.

В этом случае мы можем оставить исходный код автора как есть, но должны добавить к нему недостающий код:

1. Запись `persons_id` в сессию.
2. Перенаправление на главную с помощью НТТР заголовка `Location:` и функции `header()`.
3. На главной мы из сессии читаем `persons_id` и определяем юзера. Далше мы можем вывести его id.

Comment: Здравствуите Ипатиев, нужна Вариант 1- Лотерея, авторизация не нужна. Друг хочет программу, где просто заходят пользователи и в конце недели будет разигриваьтся  лотерея , выигривает тот, кто больше других заходил, а источником прибила будут рекламы. Я программирую на локальном, а опить веб-программирования нет. Хочет после авторизации чтобы клиент получил свой номер из бд, но без переадресации на  select_res.php, а на index.php. (продолжение в следуюшем коммент.)

Comment: сделал как предлагали-в insert_res.php добавил(без <?php   ?> ):   header('Location: http://Lottery/index.php'/);  но выводит:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\Lottery\www\insert_res.php:1) in Z:\home\Lottery\www\insert_res.php on line 13. А если его поставить в <?php   ?>  тогда выводит:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in Z:\home\Lottery\www\insert_res.php on line 12. Та же проблема при вставке нового клиента в бд.   Если вес код insert_res.php перенесу в index.php, тогда да- ID клиента  выводится на главной форме (-->)

Comment: но зато получается как вы сказали: "главная форма быстро превратится в помойку, в которой сам черт ногу сломит", хочу соблюдать модульность программы- обработчик хранить в  отдельные php файлы. Знаю, что проблему решит ajax, но пока в php хорошо не разберусь, хочу временно обойтись без ajax.

Answer (score 3):

На главную страницу вниз перенесите код из страницы select_res.php и оберните его в if():

```html
<?php if(!empty($_POST['FirstName'])){
// тут ваш код из страницы select_res.php
} ?>
```

и на самой форме атрибут "action" оставьте пустым:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Должно работать.

Comment: Roma Slobodian, сработал. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @davidkoko Не забывайте отмечать правильные ответы

Comment: Еще один вариант - в action формы можно прописать <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>

Answer (score 0):

Если решение должно быть только на php, то один из вариантов - тот, что, предложил Roma Slobodian.

Другой вариант - можно в файле-обработчике формы после всех инструкций вызвать функцию

```
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Где http://example.com/ - адрес страницы, на которую нужно вернуться после выполнения инструкций.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php